# Separately Positioning UINavigationBar Title Vertically For Each View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, vertical-alignment, title

Despite globally altering your UINavigationBar title through the appearance proxy such as this:

**[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];**

How can you define the title's vertical height for a single view controller which I would expect to look like this:

**[self.navigationBar setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];**

But unfortunately does not work. I am trying to adjust my titles' vertical position for a specific view controller without affecting the other view controllers' UINavigationBar title position.

Comment: You may want to create your own `UILabel` and put it in as a custom view (or view hierarchy, depending on your needs) by setting the `titleView` property of your `UINavigationItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` selector to set the appearance for each individual UIViewController. It would look something like this...

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ViewControllerOne class], nil] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ViewControllerTwo class], nil] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ViewControllerThree class], nil] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.7 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Update:**

Example of how to use this by creating a `StyleManager` class:

```
@implementation StyleManager

+ (void)setApplicationStyle
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ViewControllerOne class], nil] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.3 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ViewControllerTwo class], nil] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ViewControllerThree class], nil] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.7 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // Other appearnce styling here...
}

@end
```

Once you've created your `StyleManager` you can simply use it in your `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [StyleManager setApplicationStyle];
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: How do I implement this with Storyboard because that is how I created my ViewController? Say I put your code into my app delegate and configure it to [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MainTableViewController class], nil] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: It doesn't matter that you've used storyboards. One common practice I've seen is to make a `StyleManager` or `ThemeManager` class that has a single class method that sets all of your applications specific appearance's. I've updated my answer with a small example of this.

Comment: So where do I put these appearancWhenContainedIn lines of code? In each ViewController? I would prefer not to use a tyleManager because I do not know how to set that up. Thankyou for the help can't seem to find any of this online.

Comment: Sure. It's actually really simple to setup a `StyleManager` as I've shown in the updated example above. All you'll need to do is create a new Objective-C class that is a subclass of NSObject. Name this new class something like `StyleManager`. Copy what I've shown above for the `+ (void)setApplicationStyle` method. Paste it into your new StyleManager class's implementation file. Define the method in the header file so that it's public. Then simple call this method in the `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Alright so I figured out to put [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MainNavigationController class], nil] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-2.5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; within my NavigationController file under viewDidLoad. Works like a charm for my app. Once again, thankyou for your help, this problem has been driving me crazy!

Comment: If you believe this answer helped solve your problem would you consider accepting this answer as the official answer to your question? Again, glad I could help.

Comment: I would be glad too! Any other way I can give you a good reputation report or anything on this website? Your answer really helped with a frustrating problem I've had for quite a while.